# How to use a parameter in Openrowset

Tags: sql-server-2005, openrowset

I want to use a storedprocedure as a table in another storedprocedure. Here is my code:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rapor_FaturalandirilmisFaturalandirilmamisSeansKarsilastirmasi]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @tarih1 SMALLDATETIME,
    @tarih2 SMALLDATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT  K.euclidNo
          ,K.klinik_id
          ,K.KlinikAdi 

(
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=***;UID=***;PWD=(***)',
     'EXECUTE Rapor_FaturalandirilmamisSeansSayilari ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@tarih1,102) + ''',''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR,@tarih2,102)+ '''')

) AS FATURALANMAMIS
FROM Klinikler AS K
WHERE refKlinikGrup_id=1
END
```

But it returns "Incorrct syntax near  '+' ". Do you have any suggestion about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably related to the apostrophe's -- those always give me trouble.

But regardless -- your OPENROWSET should be in your FROM clause, shouldn't it?  I'd start by fixing that.